# Cocos-2d iphone reset game board

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, variables, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a board game that when one person wins i want the board to reset itself. I am using cocos2d for iPhone if that helps. I have a reset method that resets all variables and the array of pieces. It resets once then the next time after one person wins it does not reset the board. Any ideas on how to fix this?
 Here is the method in the .m file.
//Method

```
-(void) resetGame {
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

if( (self=[super init]) ) {


    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    turn = 2;

    pieces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:1 player:1 row:1 col:3],    // bSphere1
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:1 player:1 row:2 col:3],    // bSphere2
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:1 row:1 col:2],    // bSquare1
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:1 row:3 col:3],    // bSquare2
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:1 row:0 col:3],    // bSquare3
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:1 player:2 row:0 col:4],    // wSphere1
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:1 player:2 row:2 col:4],    // wSphere2
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:2 row:1 col:4],    // wSquare1
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:2 row:3 col:4],    // wSquare2
              [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:2 player:2 row:2 col:5],    // wSquare3
              nil];

    // add background before pieces
    CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grid.png"];
    [bg setPosition:ccp(240, 160)];
    [self addChild:bg z:0];

    // add all the pieces
    for(Piece *piece in pieces) {
        [self addChild:piece];
    }

}

}
```

Comment: where do you release the Piece objects?

Comment: As @LearnCocos2D mentioned there is no code for releasing the previous pieces in your reset method. (i.e. remove the old child pieces from the parent layer with cleanup)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use that layer/CCScene for more than 1 round (it's not replaced by another intermediate CCScene like a Menu), then you should try adding/removing sprites outside the init function

you can do something like

```
- (void)resetLevel: {

//remove old children
[this removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

//Add new children
pieces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
     [[Piece alloc] pieceWithType:1 player:1 row:1 col:3],    // bSphere1
     .......
     nil];

    // add background before pieces
    CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grid.png"];
    [bg setPosition:ccp(240, 160)];
[self addChild:bg z:0];

    // add all the pieces
    for(Piece *piece in pieces) {
       [self addChild:piece];
    }
```

}

The code is not tested, you might have to do some alterations

You should also avoid retaining the NsMutableArray and Piece instances allocation (alloc ), as you have to do extra work to release them. Your layer retains them by adding them anyway

Comment: what is your "this" in the remove childrenwithcleanup?

Comment: sorry about that, i meant 'self'